# How do I get Lat/Long coordinates from Google Earth placed correctly in my current coordinate system? (NAD1983)

Tags: coordinate-system

I am having trouble with point data lining up with my coordinate system compared to Google Earth. I have these coordinates from Google Earth and I need them to be placed correctly in ArcMap. I have the layer in placed (all the info) for these points that are from Google Earth but the layer is already made and in NAD_1983 coordinate system. How do I get the points showing in the correct locations like in Google Earth but in my coordinate system within ArcMap? I am also just using the standard basemap imagery within ArcMap.

I have tried putting in the coordinates into the attribute table thinking the points would move but I don't think that is how it works.

[image: These are the coordinates from Google Earth and I need these to be exact in ArcMap]

Comment: NAD83 is a Datum. It is not a projected coordinate system. What coordinate system are you using in ArcMap?

Comment: Geographic coordinate system: GCS_North_American_1983
Projected Coordinate System: NAD_1983_StatePlane_Colorado_South_FIPS_503_Feet

Comment: Please provide an example point coordinate pair [in your question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/posts/457031/edit), even a dummy one in the general area if they're sensitive.

Comment: Updated with the coordinates.

Comment: State plane coordinates in that projection are in feet, not degrees. Adding an attribute won't change geometry unless you then update the geometry with the coordinate data. But you'd need to reproject each decimal degree point to the target SpatialReference first. This is a fairly advanced task, and insufficient information is provided.

Comment: When you add this data, define the coordinate system as 4326 (WGS 84). Convert it to a feature class or shapefile and then you can use the Project Tool to convert it to your projected coordsys: NAD 1983 state plane Colorado South zone (using US survey feet).